# How to setup health check on multiple ports in new AWS Application LB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, docker, application, healthcheck

Can someone help me setting up the multi-port health check on single AWS ALB.

My instances have been running with dockerized containers on different ports. ALB Scheme is internal LB.

Please help.

Comment: Not a duplicate.  @ceejayoz ELB 2.0 ("[Application Load Balancer](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-application-load-balancer/)") has some new tricks, apparently including [individual service checks](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/target-group-health-checks.html) (not to mention service selection by HTTP request path pattern matching).

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Ah! Cheers. Vote retracted!

Answer (score 0):

Under Loadbalancer/Target Groups:

Create each target group for each port

eg, port_8888/8888/server1 ( target_group name, port, server)

eg, port_9999/9999/server1

For the ALB, create different listeners for different ports.

eg, listener 1 / port 88 --> port_8888

eg, listener 2 / port 99 --> port_9999

In case you use one listener port and route to different target groups (or port) you can use Listener Rule.

Answer (score -4):

create multiple target group point to the same instance with different ports.
create listeners with their respective target groups

Comment: While this may be the solution, it would help if you could explain *how* to do it.

Comment: ok, suppose you have 3 instances......and you want to open ports 80-82.
1. Create a target group with those three instances with port 80

2. Create a target group with those three instances with port 81

3. Create a target group with those three instances with port 82.

Then, on the alb, create 3 listener rules each for 80, 81 & 82 and set the respective target group for each of the ports. I hope this provides necessary clarification.